# Am I implemented Single diode model correctly?

Tags: vb6, equation

I need to confirm if I have translated the following equation (*image below*) correctly to programmatic code format (Visual Basic 6).
It is an equation for the 1 diode model of a PV solar cell.

(Variable I is supposed to be the cell output Icell ?)

**Single diode model equation:**
[image]

VB code equation: (*Just showing the eqn & example variables*)

```
Icell = Ipv - Isat * (Exp((Vcell + I * Rs) / M * Vt) - 1) - ((Vcell + I * Rs) / Rp)

I = Icell ' ?

Vcell = 0.35       cell terminal voltage
Ipv   = 8.78       photon generated current
Isat  = 2.73e-10   Diode reverse saturation(scale current)
Rs    = 0.055      Series Resistance
Rp    = 100,000    Parallel Resistance
Tc    = 25.0       Device temperature
M     = 1          Diode Ideal factor(Emission Coefficient)
```

Inputs to VB equation are copied from my circuit simulation.

Comment: I would put M * Vt in parens. More readable and if the order of operations wasn't as expected, this avoids a bug.